# Android studio 'test' app no longer updating to new code (server ip address)

Tags: android, ip-address

so for the past 4 days this has been working fine up until this morning. Im currently developing an app that searches an SQL database and to do so without paying for one I set up a local Database. Because it isn't hosted, the ip address for it changes each day and i have to update it in the code

```
// Enter URL address where your php file resides       
url = new URL("http://172.17.0.171/test/fish-search.php");
```

typically, after running `ipconfig` in the cmd prompt, I would just replace the old ipv4 address with the newly assigned one but as of this morning the changes are not being pushed/shown when i run the app as I am getting Json Query errors that display "unable to connect to 172.17.0.138 at port 80" which was yesterdays ip. How do i fix this so that i can continue to edit on this project.

Comment: Any takers on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could not be a problem with your app, for I faced the same issue so often with Android Studio 2.0. Simply though, the workaround was to just uninstall the app and then run it from scratch. Also, I noted that 'Instant Run' sometings contributed to that strange issue. When 'Rerun' did not solve it, the former way did. Haven't yet got my hands on  AS 2.1, but the release note for 2.1.2 said:

> Instant Run updates and bug fixes

May be it was fixed!

Comment: I disabled instant run and it still doesn't work. Are you suggesting completely uninstalling Android studio and re-trying it then? I'm not following you on the "uninstall the app"? I would hate to have to code it all over again

Comment: Nope. WAIT. What exactly do you mean by " 'Test' app" ? Where do you test it?

Comment: the green Play button that say Run App. That's what ive been using to test it successfully up until today. As it no longer shows new code just the older stuff. Like it wont update or shut down when i close it down

Comment: No, I mean't whether an actual device or an emulator. Never mind, what I said was to UNINSTALL your app(from settings, you sure know how) from the device (or) emulator and then try hitting the green play button just like you normally would.

Comment: ah ok. I uninstalled it but when i go to run it now it is no longer on the emulator? What are your thoughts on how to get it to come back up? sorry for the probably simple questions this is my first app ever

Comment: basically, how to I install it now?

Comment: You need to press the green play button and wait till the app opens on the screen, which should take 2-5 minutes depending on your AS Version

Comment: @WChampion And if it worked, don't forget to click the grey check mark just left to my answer. If it didn't, come back and post any issue you may face, even if you think it is 'so simple'

Comment: will do, still waiting for it to install however

Comment: still not working but you managed to get me halfway. Ill post another on how to install

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Until what point did it work?

Comment: Like It still hasnt re-installed on the emulator since uninstalling it

Comment: @WChampion Sorry for late reply, has it now?

Comment: nope, like my app is completely broken now haha. the search nav bar wont search anymore so im just gonna re code it in my free time. What a shame

Comment: Oops, sorry though. May be in the process of fixing your IP issue, you broke some of the search feature. Best of luck for your quest!